# Linq query with group by yields no results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
IEnumerable<EFDBActivityActual> _tempList = 
    context.ActivityActual
           .Include(a => a.ExercisesActualList.Select(b => b.AerobicActual.IntensityFactor))
           .Include(a => a.ExercisesActualList.Select(b => b.ResistanceActual.IntensityFactor))
           .Include(a => a.ExercisesActualList.Select(b => b.ResistanceActual.ResistanceSetList))
           .Include(a => a.ActivityLocation)
           .Include(a => a.ActivityTemplate)
           .Where(a => a.QserID == session.UserID &&
                 (a.CreatedOn >= _fromDate && a.CreatedOn <= _toDate) &&
                 ((a.ExercisesActualList.Count() != 0) && a.StartTime != null));


var dx = from a in _tempList
             select new
             {
                 weeknumber = WeekNumber(a.CreatedOn),
                 activity = a
             };

    var g = from ax in dx
            group ax by ax.weeknumber
            into bx
            select bx;
```

Can someone help me what's going on here, I really don't know what was happening with this query. It will always give me an error that : *Results View = The type '<>f__AnonymousType1' exists in both 'KoolHealth.Server.dll' and 'System.Web.dll'*

The first anonymous query it will give me results, but on the second one with group by, it will not.

Comment: Looks like that you didn't show all your code?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find out why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var g = from ax in dx
        group ax by new { ax.weeknumber } into bx
        select new bx;
```